# GridView with filter menu button in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-menu, android-adapterview, android-filter

I have some troubles: I've got a simple `GridView`, in which I have two categories of items. I wanted to add three `Menu Buttons` to have a `Filter` for this GridView and *show/hide* the items with the category selected.

For the example, with the following image, the first image represents my simple `GridView` with the `Button in ActionBar`. When I press the Button, a `SubMenu` displays three rows which are, for this example: "*All*", "*Open*" & "*Closed*". And when I press the "*Open*" button, I want to show only the items with category "*Open*":

[image]

I found several things for `Search Editext` with the implements `Filterable` but I don't think it's a good way to achieve what I want. I don't need a `TextView/EditText` as filter, just a Button in `ActionBar`.

---

### UPDATE:

*Note: I updated my `Adapter` after modifications with [@ana01's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22026877/2668136).*

It seems that `getView()` are called once too much. I added 3 `Integers` to count the number of items with their categories (*nValues* = total, *nOpen* = nb of Open item, *nClosed* = nb of Closed item). I used **notifyDataSetChanged()** to update my adapter.

Here's my `Activity` with my `BaseAdapter`:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    ActionBar actionbar;
    static GridView gridview;
    static MyAdapter adapter;

    String[] values = new String[] { 
        "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"
    };

    // 1 for Open items, 2 for Closed items
    int[] vStatus = new int[] {
        1, 2, 1, 2, 1
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            // new Intent to another Activity
            // ...
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // call an adapter method filterView() 
    // with the integer sort by category
    // 0 = All items | 1 = Open | 2 = Closed
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                return false;
            case R.id.action_listfilter_all :
                adapter.filterView(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_listfilter_open :
                adapter.filterView(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_listfilter_closed :
                adapter.filterView(2);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        // Initialize the category's integer "visibleFlag"
        private int visibleFlag = 0;
        // Initialize the counters' categories
        int nValues, nOpen, nClosed;

        public MyAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        // filterView method called by option selected item menu
        public void filterView(int i) {
            visibleFlag = i;

            // refresh the content
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            /* gridview.invalidateViews(); */
        }

        protected class ViewHolder {
            TextView text, view, like, user, coms;
            ImageView imageview, imageflag;
        }

        // return the number of items regarding by category selected
        public int getCount() {
            switch(visibleFlag) {
                case 0: nValues = values.length; break;
                case 1: nValues = nOpen; break;
                case 2: nValues = nClosed; break;
            }
            return nValues;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((MainActivity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                viewHolder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                // set the tag of the category and 
                // augment the selected category (by + 1)
                switch(vStatus[position]) {
                    case 1: viewHolder.imageview.setTag(1); nOpen++; break;
                    case 2: viewHolder.imageview.setTag(2); nClosed++; break;
                }

                // set the tag of the item's position
                viewHolder.text.setTag(position);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // display the text with the position's tag
            viewHolder.text.setText(values[(Integer) viewHolder.text.getTag()]);

            // display the image with the position's tag
            switch((Integer) viewHolder.imageview.getTag()) {
                case 1: viewHolder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_open); break;
                case 2: viewHolder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_closed); break;
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

But this does not display the right items with the selected category!
Can somebody help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need the first two lines only, because `gridView.setAdapter(adapter)` doesn't make sense if the adapter is already set.

I don't think you need an AsynkTask for refreshing your collection, just modify your adapter to be aware of item types: when the filter is set (an integer that represent one of the 3 states: *all*, *closed*, *opened*), your adapter should report the correct count and return the proper item (you could use 3 different item collections, although this means duplicating your data).

`gridView.notifyDataChanged()` triggers a new `getCount()` call in your adapter, followed by multiple calls to `getView(..)`. The `gridView.invalidateViews()` says that child views need to be redrawn. You don't need to recreate the gridView.

If your items should look similar to what you drawn, I think you could use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) (with the same adapter).

**Update**:
It's OK if `getCount()` is getting called multiple times, but you should avoid performing heavy tasks in this method (not the case at the moment).

In `getView(..)` you should deliver a view which is fully synchronized with the corresponding position, no matter if you reuse a previously created one or not. So the problem is that you are updating the view only if it's freshly created `(convertView==null)`, although you should update the title's text &CO. right before the view is returned.
Related to your "ghost item", I don't know how big are your layout items, if they are visible all at once etc., but your adapter should create at least as many views as the visible ones.

**Update2**:

Modify your adapter as below, call `prepareData()` in your adapter's constructor, and see if it's working:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> closedIndexToRealIndex;
private ArrayList<Integer> openedIndexToRealIndex;

private void prepareData(){
    nOpen = nClosed = 0;
    closedIndexToRealIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    openedIndexToRealIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.count; i++){
        if(vStatus[i] == 0){    
            openedInexToRealIndex.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
            nOpen++;
        }
        else{
            closedIndexToRealIndex.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
            nClosed++;
       }
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((MainActivity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                viewHolder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            int actualIndex = 0;
            switch(visibleFlag){
            case 0://all
                actualIndex = position;
                break;
            case 1://opened
                actualIndex = openedIndexToRealIndex.get(position).intValue();
                break;
            case 2://closed
                actualIndex = closedIndexToRealIndex.get(position).intValue();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            viewHolder.text.setText(values[acutalIndex]);

            if(vStatus[position] == 1)
                viewHolder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_open);
            else
                viewHolder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_closed);

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question. BTW, I choose `GridView` because I want to display 2 items by row on landscape mode. It's a little tip to faking a `ListView`'s appearance.

Comment: I updated my question according to your suggestions. But this isn't working after many, many modifications. Could you help me with this? Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: I've updated my answer, although it's edited with notepad, it should work. You're welcome!

Comment: I really appreciate. I just make two changes in your **getView method**: 1- `openedIndexToRealIndex[position].intValue()` has the error "This expression must be an array type", it became `openedIndexToRealIndex.get(position).intValue()` | 2- This didn't change the image according by the item position, so this: `vStatus[position]`, it became `valuesS[actualIndex]`. Finally, it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!